# zabbix macro for current date in YYYYMMDD format

Tags: zabbix

I need to retrieve numeric values from a log file and later on build a graph.
The path of the file in question is changing based on today's date like this :

```
/path/to/file/YYYYMMDD/file.log
```

Is there any way (macro?) to get current date in such format so it could be used in a zabbix key ?

Answer (score 1):

There aren't any native way to do it, even with log monitoring key.

You can handle it with a low [level discovery rule](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/4.4/manual/discovery/low_level_discovery) which runs a custom discovery script, a simple `bash + ls + sed/awk` will do the trick.

Make it run every N minutes against `/path/to/file` to produce an lld compliant output:

```
[
    { "{#FILENAME}":"20191011"  },
    { "{#FILENAME}":"20191012"  },
    { "{#FILENAME}":"20191013"  },
[cut]
```

Then you can use the `{#FILENAME}` macro in items and trigger prototypes.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, however as I am a total noob in Zabbix this might be a bit of an advanced topic for me to make it work in a reasonable amount of time. Another approach I thought is to create a custom bash script, sending the data I want to Zabbix via the `zabbix_sender` command/tool. Do you think that would work ?

Comment: It's difficult to say, it depends on what exactly you need to do. If you dont'want to proceed with LLD: I'm not a fan of `zabbix_sender`, I'd prefer to create a `system.run` item to run a script at defined intervals, to get the data I need. All of the intelligence and logic of directory and data handling will be inside the script.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [{TIME} macro](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/6.0/en/manual/appendix/macros/supported_by_location?hl=Macro) in combination with the [fmttime macro function](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/6.0/en/manual/config/macros/macro_functions?hl=Macro%2Cfunctions%2Cmacro) to create any time layout you want.
The following will create a time in the YYYYmmdd format.

```
{{TIME}.fmttime(%Y%d%m)}
```